# How to stop barbell rotating in elbow when doing zercher squat?

Tags: squats

When unracking the barbell for the zercher squat, the barbell sometimes rolls in the valley created my elbows and it hurts quite a bit. Anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unintended rolling of the bar is often due to the bar being bent.**

Put the empty bar on the ground and roll it back and forth, looking for any vertical movement in the centre of the bar. If the centre of the bar moves up and down slightly as it rolls, then the bar is bent. If you're unable to get the bar replaced, all you can really do is roll the bar around while it's still in the rack in order to get the centre to the highest point so that it won't roll further when you unrack.

If you need to convince your gym that they should replace the bar, you can raise it as a safety concern, as bent bars can easily roll out of the lifter's hands during a bench press and cause the bar to fall onto them.

Answer (score 2):

I put a foam neck pad on the bar to protect my elbows. Zercher squats hurt my elbows too much with a bare bar. The neck pad also prevents the bar from rotating.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).